# Reverse Integer in Scala

Tags: scala, recursion, functional-programming

I've been trying to figure out a way to reverse an integer in scala (e.g. 1932 -> 2391) without converting to string and in a purely functional way. My goal is to reverse the Int by converting to List then just using List().reverse then converting back to Int.

```
    def reverseIntList(x: Int) : List[Int] = {
      if (!(x <= 0))
        if ((x > 0) && (x < 10))
          x
        else
          (x % 10) :: reverseIntList(x / 10) :: Nil

      else
       List()
     }
```

However, I only get this error code:
recursive method reverseIntList needs result type

Comment: I cannot reproduce your problem. The code you posted *cannot possibly* cause the error you posted, if only for the obvious reason that there *is no* method named `func` in your code.

Comment: My bad, I had used func for the name of the function initially but I changed it to reverseIntList for clarity.

Comment: I still cannot reproduce your problem. The code you posted *cannot possibly* cause the error you posted, if only for the obvious reason that `reverseIntList` clearly *does* have a result type annotation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First `unfold()` it, then `fold()` it back up. No `.reverse` needed.

```
def reverseInt(x: Int): Int =
  List.unfold(x)(n => Option.when(n > 0)((n%10,n/10)))
      .fold(0)(_ * 10 + _)
```

Answer (score 1):

You are returning an Int instead of List[Int] for the first condition.

Also, some enhancement to apply to your code.

- No need in this case for the ":: Nil" to construct your list.
- No need for "(x > 0)" condition, as it’s already verified by your first if.

It should look like this.

```
 def reverseIntList(x: Int): List[Int]  = {
    if (!(x <= 0))
      if ((x < 10))
        List(x)
      else
        x % 10 :: reverseIntList(x / 10)
    else
      List()
  }
```